# Discord.js Display Reddit Post's Title

Tags: javascript, discord.js, reddit

I have this code that gets a random post from the top of r/memes and I want it to display the random post's title that it picked.

```
if(msg.content === '-meme')
  {
    var Channel = msg.channel.name
        if(Channel != "chill-bot-log" && Channel != "chill-shitpost") {
            msg.channel.send(msg.author + ' ezt a parancsot nem használhatod ebben a csatornában');
            console.info(msg.author + " megpróbálta loggolni a botot egy rossz csatornában.");
        } else {
    loadMemes(message);
  }
    function loadMemes() {
    fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes.json?limit=800&?sort=hot&t=all')
    .then(res => res.json())
    //.then(res => console.log(res))
    .then(json => json.data.children.map(v => v.data.url))
    .then(urls => postRandomMeme(urls));
    }

    function postRandomMeme(urls) {
    const randomURL = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length) + 1];
    const redditUrl = `https://www.reddit.com${randomURL.reddit}`;
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
    image: {
    url: randomURL
    }
    });
    embed.setFooter('Subreddit : r/memes')
    embed.setTitle(redditUrl)
    msg.channel.send(embed);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I know that everyone will tell me to use randompuppy, but I just want to use this code I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function loadMemes() {
  // Fetch JSON
  return fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes.json?limit=800&?sort=hot&t=all')
    .then(res => res.json())
    // Return the actual posts
    .then(json => json.data.children);
}

function postRandomMeme(message) {
  return loadMemes().then(posts => {
    // Get a random post's title and URL
    const {title, url} = posts[Math.floor(Math.random() * posts.length)].data;
    // Create the embed
    // For Discord.js v11 replace MessageEmbed with RichEmbed
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed({
      title,
      image: {url},
      footer: {text: 'Subreddit : r/memes'}
    });
    // Send the embed
    // For Discord.js v11/v12 use .send(embed)
    return message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
  })
}

// Usage:
postRandomMeme(msg)
  // Log all errors
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: const {title, url} = posts[Math.floor(Math.random() * posts.length)];
          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'

Comment: I fixed it but now it won't work, I'll post the error when I wake up

Comment: Oh yeah it won't use loadmemes

Comment: @VasDávidValentin Sorry, just forgot a `{` and a `)`. I’ve edited my answer.

Comment: loadMemes().then(posts => {
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: I think you need to define the thing after posts but IDK what to define it as

Comment: @VasDávidValentin I've edited my answer again (added `return` in `loadMemes`). Sorry for all the mistakes.

Comment: For some reason it says that "loadMemes" is undefined but it is a function

Comment: It isn't working, I only get this : https://i.imgur.com/rwhoRaz.png

Comment: For some reason it won't get the pic or the name of the post or anything

Comment: I console.info-d it and it said undefined for both of them. ```console.info({title, url});```

Comment: @VasDávidValentin I fixed it, sorry for not testing the code. `posts[Math.floor(Math.random() * posts.length)].data` (didn't have the `.data` before). That should work now.